# How can I configure the Buildship plugin to download the Maven API Javadoc in Eclipse?

Tags: groovy, gradle-plugin, gradle-eclipse, buildship

I am building a gradle plugin in Groovy using Eclipse Neon 3. I have linked the internal dependencies as below, and have generated an Eclipse configuration using the Eclipse gradle plugin.

```
dependencies {
compile gradleApi()
compile localGroovy()}
```

I have specified that I would like to download and receive source code and Javadoc for dependencies:

```
eclipse {
classpath {
    downloadSources = true
    downloadJavadoc = true
}}
```

For all dependencies but the internal ones, this works. I am not receiving source code or javadoc api for the following:

1. gradle-api-3.5.jar
2. groovy-all-2.4.10.jar
3. gradle-installation-beacon-3.5.jar
4. gradle-test-kit-3.5.jar

Given that these are very important to understand the framework,
*my question is:*

**How do I configure a groovy-based gradle plugin project in Eclipse, such that the above four libraries have JavaDoc and Source navigation available?**

Comment: Same question for Java in the Gradle forum w/o any answer yet: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-get-javadoc-for-gradle-api-for-custom-tasks-or-plugins-in-eclipse/29280

Comment: A related issue at GitHub: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1003